# Create PHP array's on the fly

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am having the worst time trying to get this to work.  In the following code, I am gathering data from a database query and trying to build a muti-dimensional array object that will keep totals and tally up some information in a specific way.  The problem is that instead of getting a value that is incrementing as it should, the value seems to be suffering from the last value it was assigned problem.  Here is the code:

```
        $REVIEWS      = array();
        $USER_REVIEWS = array();
        $USER_IMGREVS = array();


        pseudo-code: loop here which iterates over the DB results creating
        $date - which is into this function as its called for each day of month
        $p1user - which is one of the users (there are 3) 'levels' of users
        $hr - is the hour which is built from the transaction's timestamp

        $hr     = date('H', $row['P1TIMESTAMP']);
        $p1user = $row['P1USER'];

        $REVIEWS[$date] += 1;
        $USER_REVIEWS[$date][$p1user][$hr] += 1;
        $USER_IMGREVS[$date][$p1user][$hr] += $row['F5'];

        print "PASS1<br/>\n";
        print "Value of Total Reviews: [".$REVIEWS[$date]."]<br/>\n";
        print "Value of User Reviews: [".$USER_REVIEWS[$date][$p1user][$hr]."]<br/>\n";
        print "Value of Reviewed Images: [".$USER_IMGREVS[$date][$p1user][$hr]."]<br/>\n";
        print "<br/><br/>\n";
```

So - the 'total reviews' increments by one, as it should, for each time i print this.  SO far so good.  The next two arrays will only print the last values they were assigned, and will not be added together like they should.  Why not?  I have attempted to do this another way by literally creating the arrays one by one and assigning them in whole to the array containing them - but that also does not seem to work.  Any insights?

Comment: Can we some more of the code above this where the other parts of the array are created?

Comment: Do a `print_r` of the arrays and have a look at their structure.

Comment: Can you provide more code please? where do you initilize your array, the loop you collecting the data, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know how you initilize your array, maybe this will help:

```
// replace this 2 lines:
$USER_REVIEWS[$date][$p1user][$hr] += 1;
$USER_IMGREVS[$date][$p1user][$hr] += $row['F5'];

// with this code:
if (!isset($USER_REVIEWS[$date]))
    $USER_REVIEWS[$date] = array();
if (!isset($USER_REVIEWS[$date][$p1user]))
    $USER_REVIEWS[$date][$p1user] = array();
if (!isset($USER_REVIEWS[$date][$p1user][$hr]))
    $USER_REVIEWS[$date][$p1user][$hr] = 0;
$USER_REVIEWS[$date][$p1user][$hr] += 1;

if (!isset($USER_IMGREVS[$date]))
    $USER_IMGREVS[$date] = array();
if (!isset($USER_IMGREVS[$date][$p1user]))
    $USER_IMGREVS[$date][$p1user] = array();
if (!isset($USER_IMGREVS[$date][$p1user][$hr]))
    $USER_IMGREVS[$date][$p1user][$hr] = 0;
$USER_IMGREVS[$date][$p1user][$hr] += $row['F5'];
```

Comment: MAGNIFICENT!  Apparently I cannot create the arrays on the fly without first telling PHP that the new reference is for an array.  I am used to perl where this is not necessary.  Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, I dont understand very well why your coed is not working, but in my first test, I would change these lines:

```
$count = 1;
$USER_REVIEWS[$count][$p1user][$hr] += 1;
$USER_IMGREVS[$count][$p1user][$hr] += $row['F5'];
$count++;
```

Please, check if this code helps you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your print statements for those values rely on the value of $p1user:

```
print "Value of User Reviews: [".$USER_REVIEWS[$date][$p1user][$hr]."]<br/>\n";
print "Value of Reviewed Images: [".$USER_IMGREVS[$date][$p1user][$hr]."]<br/>\n";
```

If you want to print it for all users you should loop over all possible users rather than just using $p1user. Either that or add them up if you want their sum.

**Edit:**  Something that was bugging me was your data structure.  It doesn't seem to represent your data very well.  In your loop why don't you build up useful information that you store at the base of the review array?